# Blocked script execution in because the document's frame is sandboxed - Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, sandbox

I have strange problem - when deploying app (pure angular application with rest api) to production server and accessing its url via link from other site (ref from email for example) I have got blank page - firefox say nothing, chrome says

> Blocked script execution in 'URL of website' because the document's
>   frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

and blocks all my .js files...

what does it means? I have found on the Internet something about iframes but I have no iframes in my site...

Strangest thing in my opinion is that if I access that link directly everything works without any problem...

So how to avoid to this behaviour?

Thanks for any reply

Comment: If 'email' means a webclient it's more likely that the site opens in sandboxed iframe, i mean it's not opened directly in your browser

Comment: maybe you have some very weird strict firewall policies inside your companys network ?

Comment: I use mailtrap.io for emails, and that email (with link) is opened in iframe - maybe that is the problem, but I don't understand how iframe can affect redirecting to other site (I would understand if whole site would be opened in that iframe)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**The error message warns that an Iframe is sand-boxed without a proper privileges**

Yes, you are clicking in an iFrame. This is an example of a sand-boxed iFrame.

```
<iframe sandbox src="http://usercontent.example.net/getusercontent.cgi?id=12193"></iframe>
```

If you **inspect element** on GMail, you will notice iFrames everywhere. The sandbox attribute is not always automatically attached, because the sandbox attribute controls what is allowed.

When a pop-up is needed, the attribute will change

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://usercontent.example.net/getusercontent.cgi?id=12193"></iframe>
```

This is done to protect the user and the mail application from **XSS**

The iFrame has to allow pop-ups, new windows, or scripts. Whatever you are trying (probably just navigation), the action is being blocked by a sandbox.

Comment: ">Yes, you are clicking in an iFrame." I don't think so. This error message occurs when I gets redirected from mailtrap.io to my AngularJS application.

Comment: Strange... I just tried to reproduce this error - it's gone. What I did is turn off my Mac (my Angular development app version runs locally) and then turn it on again.

Comment: This error can happen without an iframe element