# Why inserting of YouTube video doesn't work in the case of nested frames

Tags: html, youtube

I have the following files:

**index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <style>  
   iframe {
      border: none;
      display: block;
   }
   </style>
</head>    
<body>
   <iframe id="main-frame" src="child.htm" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**child.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw" 
        title="Me at the zoo" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If we run `index.htm` then we will get the error that js is unavailable. However, I checked the settings in my browser and claim that javascript is not blocked by it. I tested this in Firefox and Google Chrome and got the same error.

**Q1:** Why do we get an error about the unavailability of js?

**Q2:** How to fix it without changes of architecture of `iframes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sandbox="allow-same-origin **allow-scripts**" try again as.

and you can find the details here. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531061/blocked-script-execution-in-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-angular)