# Blocked script execution in '<URL>' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set

Tags: javascript, angular

I have strange problem - when deploying app (pure angular application with rest api) to production server and accessing its url via link from other site (ref from email for example) I have got blank page - firefox say nothing, chrome says

> Blocked script execution in 'URL of website' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

and blocks all my .js files.

what does it means? I have found on the Internet something about iframes but I have no iframes in my site.

Strangest thing in my opinion is that if I access that link directly everything works without any problem.

So how to avoid to this behaviour?

Comment: Why was this tagged with jenkins?  Is there anything relevant to jenkins in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit funny that this question is a replica of [Blocked script execution in because the document's frame is sandboxed - Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531061/blocked-script-execution-in-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-angular?rq=2). This is most likely the cause of your error. However, to provide more clarification, it'd be helpful if you provided the code from which the error generated.

Comment: Yaa sure. This que is same but did not find Answer for it .